# Vuetify Data Table Expand Row on Column Click

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-slot

I have a vuetify data table that includes expandable rows. The only real difference I have from [the demo](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#expandable-rows) is that I would like the `item.name` column to open/close the expandable row just like the chevron icon. When I put an `@click` handler on the v-slot for that column I get the error `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: expand is not a function"`. This is the only column I need to customize so I would like to not have to build out the entire `<tr>` v-slot by hand. A scaled-down code example is below. Thanks.

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="products"
    item-key="productCode"
    show-expand
    :expanded.sync="expanded"
>

  <template v-slot:item.name="{ item, expand, isExpanded }" >
    <h4 class="my-2" @click="expand(!isExpanded)">{{ item.name }} located in {{ item.depot | camelToWords }}</h4>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
    <ProductDetailExpandedRow :currentProduct="item" :headers="headers"/>
  </template>

</v-data-table>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          value: 'name',
        },
        {
          text: 'Product ID',
          value: 'productCode',
        },
        {
          text: 'Stock',
          value: 'stock',
        },
6 more columns continue on here...
      ],
      products: [],
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Column click

Here is how you could do it with a specific column click.  Put a `@click` handler in the column's slot template.  This handler receives the column data on click.  In this case, the column's name is `name`:

```html
<template v-slot:item.name="slotData">
   <div @click="clickColumn(slotData)">{{ slotData.item.name }}</div>
</template>
```

Expanded rows are tracked in the `expanded` array, so add this row's data.  But if it's already there, remove it (because then you're trying to collapse an already expanded column)

```js
clickColumn(slotData) {
  const indexRow = slotData.index;
  const indexExpanded = this.expanded.findIndex(i => i === slotData.item);
  if (indexExpanded > -1) {
    this.expanded.splice(indexExpanded, 1)
  } else {
    this.expanded.push(slotData.item);
  }
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/LYRoQML) (Rows expand when clicking the first column, within the padding)

#### Row click

Here is how you could do it with a *row* click (i.e. any column).  In the template, add a listener to the `<v-data-table>` for the `click:row` event:

```html
<v-data-table @click:row="clickRow">
...
</v-data-table>
```

This event passes two arguments: the item, and the item slot data, including the index of the clicked row.  Use this information to modify the `this.expanded` array which tracks all expanded rows:

```js
clickRow(item, event) {
  if(event.isExpanded) {
    const indexExpanded = this.expanded.findIndex(i => i === item);
    this.expanded.splice(indexExpanded, 1)
  } else {
    this.expanded.push(item);
  }
}
```

This adds the item to the `expanded` array or it removes it by finding the index and using `splice`.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/eYdjMrB) (Rows expand when clicking anywhere in the row)

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with manually expand items in table

I had to add **id** in array like this

```
data() {
    return {
      expanded: [
        {
          id: "cbfa8ad4-4042-4ffa-b909-e8ce49c11aa0",
        },
        {
          id: "6fb8d2b4-0112-4349-afed-e6a6fbdc24fa",
        },
      ],
```